# How can I 'transfer' an application I made on VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop to Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am a complete beginner. My teacher told me that Visual Basic Express 2012 for Windows Desktop is free, so I installed it and made an application on it. Just a few days ago I realised that I had been working on a 30 day trial. I somehow want to 'transfer' the application I made from VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop to Visual Studio 2015. The way I think I can do it is by setting up the design again and copying and pasting the code. I tried searching up how to do it, but couldn't find anything (most probably due to lack of my vocabulary). Can someone please tell me if there is a better way of 'transferring' my application or leave a link down there which can probably help me find out any better ways to do it.

Comment: Did you try to open your project/solution file with Vs2015?

Comment: Hi you simply need to sign up for DreamSpark.  see http://www.dreamspark.com [link](http://www.dreamspark.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I worked on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

None of the "Express" branded products are 30-day trials, so I'm not sure exactly what situation you were in. Furthermore Visual Studio Community Edition is a fully-fledged copy of Visual Studio available for free with the only caveat being that you aren't a multi-million dollar company. And finally: students can get free copies of Visual Studio through our Dreamspark program.

The Express editions thesedays only exist for the benefit of for-profit organisations that need to hack something together in C# without needing to worry about expense-reports for editions that cost money.

(So my point is, you can use a more beefy version of Visual Studio without worrying! See here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx )

Anyway!

You don't need to do anything! Just open your `*.vbproj` file directly in Visual Studio 2015 and it will just work. You might get an "Upgrade" prompt about converting the project files to the new VS2015 format, but that's it. There is absolutely no need to copy program code around. Just open the project or solution (`*.sln`) file from within VS.

Answer (score 0):

As your a student you get access to Microsoft DreamSpark and Microsoft Imagine see http://imagine.microsoft.com

Here is a guide to setting up your DreamSpark account for FREE http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_student_developer_blog/archive/2015/08/07/how-students-get-microsoft-azure.aspx

You can download and use all the versions of Visual Studio and also use Microsoft Azure Cloud for FREE plus source control in GitHub or Visual Studio Online see [www.DreamSpark.com](http://www.DreamSpark.com)